# Excel 2010 - Add =MID in my current formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below you can see my current formula, and it already works at the moment.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("X-SKYPE-USERNAME";$A5));$A5;"")
```

But now I want to add the function =MID in this formula. (Finally goal will be that I can view a small part of the written text in cell A5.

Comment: it's not clear what are you going to achive?

Comment: I find that examples always help enormously. Can you give an sample A5 entry (or perhaps two or three) and what result you want in those cases? If the result is based on the location of "X-SKYPE-USERNAME" then it might be better to use a completely different formula

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you just change the `TRUE` result of the function, if I understand you correctly.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("X-SKYPE-USERNAME";$A5));MID($A5;[STARTING NUMBER];[NUMBER OF CHARACTERS TO GO]);"")
```

When the `IF` function evaluates to `TRUE` it will return the `MID(A5,NUMBER,NUMBER)` portion.